# Sort across rows

Tags: r, sorting, combinatorics

In R I have a combinatorics type issue.  I have columns with unique sequences, and there is a value associated with each sequence.

```
df<-cbind(data.table(rbind(
    c("A","B","C","D"), 
    c("A","C","D","B"), 
    c("A","D","B","C"), 
    c("A","C","B","D"), 
    c("A","B","D","C"), 
    c("A","D","C","B"), 
    c("A","B","D","C"), 
    c("A","D","C","B"), 
    c("A","C","B","D"), 
    c("E","B","C","D"), 
    c("E","C","D","B"), 
    c("E","D","B","C"), 
    c("E","C","B","D"), 
    c("E","B","D","C"), 
    c("E","D","C","B"), 
    c("E","B","D","C"), 
    c("E","D","C","B"), 
    c("E","C","B","D"))),
c(55,54,86,109,23,41,53,54,88,54,53,85,108,22,40,52,53,87))

> df
    V1 V2 V3 V4  V2
 1:  A  B  C  D  55
 2:  A  C  D  B  54
 3:  A  D  B  C  86
 4:  A  C  B  D 109
 5:  A  B  D  C  23
 6:  A  D  C  B  41
 7:  A  B  D  C  53
 8:  A  D  C  B  54
 9:  A  C  B  D  88
10:  E  B  C  D  54
11:  E  C  D  B  53
12:  E  D  B  C  85
13:  E  C  B  D 108
14:  E  B  D  C  22
15:  E  D  C  B  40
16:  E  B  D  C  52
17:  E  D  C  B  53
18:  E  C  B  D  87
```

The output needs to be line 4 and 13

```
> df[c(4,13),]
   V1 V2 V3 V4  V2
1:  A  C  B  D 109
2:  E  C  B  D 108
```

I need to choose the unique sequence with the largest value. 
I've thought about sorting the columns  by rows into a word and then choosing the maximum for that word, but I'm working with 12 million rows at this point.

Comment: You hsould explain what do you mean by "I need to choose the unique sequence with the largest value". You miss used the term sequence I think. Do you mean a permutation here ? Are A  B  C  D and A  C  D  B  are the "same sequence" for you ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should first create an id that aggregate your 4 factors columns. Then take the maximum by the new created id.

Regarding the size of your data, you should use `data.table` package.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
setnames(DT,5,'value')   ## just rename the column
DT[,id:=rowSums(DT[,lapply(.SD[,-5,with=F],as.integer)])][,.SD[which.max(value)],id]
  id V1 V2 V3 V4 value
1:  7  A  C  B  D   109
2:  8  E  C  B  D   108
```

Comment: Not sure, but how about: `dt[, .SD[which.max(V2.1)],by=V1]` (where `V2.1` is the last numeric col).

Answer (score 0):

Saw this passing - I'm not really handy in R so in English:

A Quick thought

- a sort is unnecessary overhead. You only need the largest value(s)
- evaluate the data row by row while updating a result variable whenever the current row is larger than the maximum so far.
- this way only one pass through the data is required.
- If you need the two largest values use the same tactic but with two result variables (one for max and one for second largest).
- If equal values are possible make the result a vector of length >1.

So don't sort but find the maximum :-)

Success

William.

Answer (score 0):

The code below produces your results but I'm sure there are several other ways of doing it. I've changed the last column to V5-Is there any reason why you have two columns named V2?

Also are you interested in the maximum value or two largest values?

The code below gives you to the rows corresponding to the 2 largest values if thats your interest:

`dimnames(df)[[2]] <- c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5")`

`df[df$V5 == tail(sort(df$V5), 2), ]`

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4  V5
1:  A  C  B  D 109
2:  E  C  B  D 108
```

The code below gives you the row with the maximum value (if thats what you're after):

`df[df$V5 == max(df$V5), ]`

```
    V1 V2 V3 V4  V5
1:  A  C  B  D  109
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using sort; it does way, way more than you need. Since this is R, avoid loops also.
Use a matrix and "max".

```
thisMat <- cbind(t(matrix(c(c("A","B","C","D"),
    c("A","C","D","B"), 
    c("A","D","B","C"), 
    c("A","C","B","D"), 
    c("A","B","D","C"), 
    c("A","D","C","B"), 
    c("A","B","D","C"), 
    c("A","D","C","B"), 
    c("A","C","B","D"), 
    c("E","B","C","D"), 
    c("E","C","D","B"), 
    c("E","D","B","C"), 
    c("E","C","B","D"), 
    c("E","B","D","C"), 
    c("E","D","C","B"), 
    c("E","B","D","C"), 
    c("E","D","C","B"), 
    c("E","C","B","D")),nrow=4)),c(55,54,86,109,23,41,53,54,88,54,53,85,108,22,40,52,53,87))

thatMat[thatMat[,5]==max(as.numeric(thatMat[,5])),]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] 
[1,] "A"  "C"  "B"  "D"  "109"
```